# Posting to WS with Restsharp is not successfull

Tags: c#, http-post, restsharp

There is an external webservice that I need to post some data to create a device. They use swagger and in the swagger I can test and it works but when I use restsharp it does not work correctly. It does not give me any error (returns 200 as status code), but it does not create a device.
PS: a GET method of Wwebservice is working but the Post is not

here is the curl when I use swagger

```
curl -X POST "website/keys/generate" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: Bearer blablablablablabla" 
-H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"deviceIds\":[\"10000000\"],\"keyNames\":[\"DeviceKey1\"],
\"externalReference\":\"ERD-1\"}"
```

as json, the request should be

```
{
  "deviceIds": [
    "10000000"
  ],
  "keyNames": [
    "DeviceKey1"
  ],
  "externalReference": "ERD-1"
}
```

and here is my code

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

request.AddParameter("deviceIds", deviceGenerationRequest.deviceIds.ToArray());
request.AddParameter("keyNames", deviceGenerationRequest.keyNames.ToArray());
request.AddParameter("externalReference", deviceGenerationRequest.externalReference);
var result = await _apiCaller.CallAPI(url, request);
```

and here is the CallAPI method's content

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
IRestResponse response; 
response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
```

What is my mistake?

**Edit:**

instead of Restsharp, I've used HttpWebResponse and it works

```
var query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceGenerationRequest);

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer blabla");

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
      streamWriter.Write(query);
    }

 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
 {
  var result3 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to post data using rest sharp

**Case 1**

Pass all the parameters as a json in single paramter and use content type to `application\json`

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n  \"deviceIds\": [\r\n    \"10000000\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"keyNames\": [\r\n    \"DeviceKey1\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"externalReference\": \"ERD-1\"\r\n}",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

**Case 2**

Pass parameters individually. If you are individually sending parameters then change content type to this

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("deviceIds", deviceGenerationRequest.deviceIds.ToArray());
request.AddParameter("keyNames", deviceGenerationRequest.keyNames.ToArray());
request.AddParameter("externalReference", deviceGenerationRequest.externalReference);
```

I am not sure about the resolution but this is most likely be the case.Apart from this everything looks good

Comment: @Muhammed thank you for the reply. Bot did not work. I've got the status OK for the second one but did not create a device. And for the first one,I've got this error from the web server {"message":"Required String parameter \u0027externalReference\u0027 is not present","status":400}

Comment: I've updated the question.. an re-write with the httpwebrequest

Comment: If you can host your api somewhere than I can work it out for you

Comment: thank you so much but the API belongs to a company that we are working with.So I do not have any access the api code..